# Using pygi, how can I override a virtual method from a GObject class that has the same name as a virtual method in its base class?

Tags: python, gstreamer, gobject, python-gstreamer, gobject-introspection

Using GObject Introspection in Python, I am trying to create a custom `PushSrc` element, which requires override `create` or `fill` virtual methods, without success.

The issue seems to be that both `PushSrc` and its base class, `BaseSrc`, has these virtual methods.

In other words, this code:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
gi.require_version('GstBase', '1.0')
from gi.repository import GstBase, Gst, GObject
Gst.init(None)


class MyPushSrc(GstBase.PushSrc):
    def __init__(self):
        self.add_pad_template(Gst.PadTemplate.new("src",
                                                  Gst.PadDirection.SRC,
                                                  Gst.PadPresence.ALWAYS,
                                                  Gst.Caps.new_any()))
        GstBase.PushSrc.__init__(self)

    def do_fill(self, buf):
        return Gst.FlowReturn.OK


GObject.type_register(MyPushSrc)
```

results in this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mypushsrc.py", line 8, in <module>
    class MyPushSrc(GstBase.PushSrc):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/types.py", line 223, in __init__
    cls._setup_vfuncs()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/types.py", line 120, in _setup_vfuncs
    ambiguous_base.__info__.get_name()
TypeError: Method do_fill() on class GstBase.PushSrc is ambiguous with methods in base classes GstBase.PushSrc and GstBase.BaseSrc
```

Unfortunately, the fact that `do_fill` in `PushSrc` has just one argument agains three in `BaseSrc` is not enough to the introspection differ these virtual methods. So, what can I do to override this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a bug in the GStreamer Python bindings which can’t currently be worked around. See the [upstream bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=695089). Solutions might become available there if anybody works on the problem.